# Creating new column with one specific value for each row, SQL Server, should be easy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to create a new column with one specific value for each row, in the same statement in which I select a view columns from a table. 
Why doesn't this work?

```
ALTER TABLE PMEBUILDING
ADD TABLEID int NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT test DEFAULT 40111
WITH VALUES

SELECT OBJECTID, BUILDINGID, RECID, TABLEID
FROM PMEBUILDING
```

It says:

> Msg 2705, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 Column names in each table must be
>   unique. Column name 'TABLEID' in table 'PMEBUILDING' is specified more
>   than once.

Comment: Removed my incorrect comment, I think I was thinking of changing a column from NOT NULL to NULL, then you have to update the column values to that are null with a value first before you can alter the column to not null.

Comment: What do you think "Column names in each table must be unique" means?

Comment: You already added `TABLEID` once, which is why the first statement fails. If `TABLEID` is not already part of the table, the *second* statement will fail, because the column is not part of the table at the time this statement is compiled. A new batch is necessary. If `TABLEID` is not already there, and you execute these statements separately, they work fine. Source: trying it with `CREATE TABLE PMEBUILDING (OBJECTID INT, BUILDINGID INT, RECID INT)` first.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes a lot of sense, I think I was sleepy. Irl laughed from @Andomar his response.

Answer (score 0):

You already have that column in the table.

Try this:

```
alter table PMEBUILDING
drop constraint test;

alter table PMEBUILDING
drop column TABLEID

alter table PMEBUILDING
ADD TABLEID int NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT test DEFAULT 40111
WITH VALUES

SELECT OBJECTID, BUILDINGID, RECID, TABLEID
FROM PMEBUILDING
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It makes a lot of sense now.